# Handling multiple query params

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a create user view and here I first register a normal user and then create a player object for that user which has a fk relation with the user.

In my case, I have three different types of users

I created a view to handle register all three different types of users, but my player user has a lot of extra model fields and storing all query params in variables will make it messy.

Is there a better way to handle this, including validation?

TLDR; I created a view to handle register all three different types of users, but my player user has a lot of extra model fields and storing all query params in variables will make it messy. Is there a better way to handle this, including validation?

This is my view.

```
class CreateUser(APIView):

    """
    Creates the User.
    """

    def post(self, request):

        email = request.data.get('email', None).strip()
        password = request.data.get('password', None).strip()
        name = request.data.get('name', None).strip()
        phone = request.data.get('phone', None)
        kind = request.query_params.get('kind', None).strip()

        print(kind)

        serializer = UserSerializer(data={'email': email, 'password':password})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        try:
            User.objects.create_user(email=email,
                                 password=password)
            user_obj = User.objects.get(email=email)

        except:
            raise ValidationError('User already exists')


        if kind == 'academy':
            Academy.objects.create(email=email, name=name, phone=phone, user=user_obj)

        if kind == 'coach':
            Coach.objects.create(email=email, name=name, phone=phone, user=user_obj)

        if kind == 'player':
            Player.objects.create(----------)

        return Response(status=200)
```

Comment: Why are you not using a `ModelSerializer` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Model Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

In your case, define it in `serializers.py` like this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class CustomBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['user'] = self.context['user']
        return super(CustomBaseSerializer, self).create(validated_data)


class PlayerSerializer(CustomBaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('count', 'height', 'right_handed', 'location',
                  'size', 'benchmark_swingspeed',
                  'benchmark_impactspeed', 'benchmark_stance',
                  'benchmark_balanceindex',)


class AcademySerializer(CustomBaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Academy
        fields = '__all__'  # Usually better to explicitly list fields


class CoachSerializer(CustomBaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Coach
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then in your view

```
class CreateUser(APIView):
    """
    Creates the User.
    """
    def post(self, request):
        print(kind)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=request.data.get('email'))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        else:
            raise ValidationError('User already exists')

        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        user_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        user = user_serializer.save()

        if kind == 'academy':
            serializer_class = AcademySerializer

        if kind == 'coach':
            serializer_class = CoachSerializer

        if kind == 'player':
            serializer_class = PlayerSerializer

        serializer = serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'user': user})
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data)  # Status is 200 by default so you don't need to include it. RESTful API's should return the instance created, this also delivers the newly generated primary key back to the client.
        # Oh and if you do serialize the object in the response, write serializers for academy and coach too, so the api response is consistent
```

Serializers are really powerful and useful. It is well worth thoroughly reading the docs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, Truly appreciate it. I was reading the docs and had done a similar implementation using model serializers but yours is much better and have given me more ideas. Reading the docs really helps :)

Comment: Anyway, I got a new error:

```{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}```

but I am passing the user `serializer = serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'user': user})`

Comment: Anyway figured it out, had to exclude users in the serializer and wasn't returning the object instance from the custom base serializer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Sorry for those little bugs :S

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd recommend to POST the parameters in a JSON or a form, instead of using the query params. But regardless the method, the solution is pretty much the same.

First, you could define the fields you're interested in a list. For example:

```
FIELDS = (
    'count',
    'height',
    'right_handed',
    'location',
    'size',
    'benchmark_swingspeed',
    'benchmark_impactspeed',
    'benchmark_stance',
    'benchmark_balanceindex',
)
```

And then get all the values from the query params and store them in a dict, like:

```
player_params = {}
for field in FIELDS:
    player_params[field] = request.query_params.get(field)
```

Now you have all the params required for a player in a dict and you can pass it to the Player model as **kwargs. Of course you'll probably need some validation. But in the end, you'll be able to do the following:

```
Player.objects.create(user=user_obj, **player_params)
```